# Targeting specific files/folders for browser caching

Tags: apache, caching

Through research, I have yet to find a clear answer.

I know that you can set headers to cache specific extensions such as .jpg, .png, .js, etc. But no where have I found if you can target a folder or a specific file to cache on the client browser.

Here's our senario: we have massive sprites (up in the thousands of pixels) that hold most of the images on our site. We want to embrace the local caching on the client browser but at the same time want to specify what folders or specific files should use the browser cache (not just the overall apache headers).

Is this possible? If so, how can it best be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would [this article](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/cache/) help?

So you'd have something like:

```
<Directory "/website/path/to/images">
    ....

    and within here can target extensions too

    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|png)$">
        ...
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Comment: In addition you should adopt a fingerprinting scheme. If you are using far-future headers, you have to fingerprint (unique string in the filename) the files otherwise you cannot update them - they may be cached on the net somewhere.